# Is there HTTP support for mariaDB?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

For writing API's for MySQL, it by default provided HTTP plug-in for all the operations. Is there similar facility is available for MariaDB also?
I searched but did not get any helpful information.

Comment: Clarify your question please, best with a code example, or documentation links

Comment: Huh?  HTTP and databases do not connect -- except through PHP, etc.

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub
 Hi. As I found we can perform operations over MySQL using HTTP. you can see [here] (https://scriptingmysql.wordpress.com/2015/01/15/mysql-5-7-labs-and-the-http-plugin-inserting-updating-and-deleting-records-in-mysql-via-http/) , similarly can we perform on Maria DB too?

Comment: @VladislavVaintroub - Hmmm... Is there an official (non-Lab) writeup on it?  Or did the plugin die?

Comment: @RickJames, no idea. I think, due to lack of documentation, Oracle might have dropped it, possibly  in favor of xplugin, which unfortunately is a little more awkward from client-side JavaScript due to its lacking HTTP.  pratik, nope, there is no such thing in MariaDB